# I need to find out how many zeros the function $f(z) = z^5 +2+e^z$ has in the left half plane by considering a D-shaped contour.

Tags: complex-analysis

I need to consider the D-shaped contour from *-iR* to *iR* of radius *R*. I am thinking, that this contour covers the whole LHplane in the limit *$R \rightarrow \infty$* so by considering the argument principle, if I can calculate
*$$ \int_\gamma \frac{f^{'}(z)}{f(z)}dz$$* I should be able to get a value for the number of zeros, since *f(z)* has no poles.
But this is where I am struggling to get anywhere, so if I can get any pointers that would be great!

Comment: 1. Dont forget to divide by $2\pi i$ 2. this is definitely a valid approach however the integral you're going to get seems to be very ugly and hard to integrate, so maybe trying reasoning by other methods?

Comment: @BenjaminSt. I think the way to go is probably through calculating the winding number, but I am confused as to how to calculate the composition of f with my D-shaped contour $\gamma$ to get $\Gamma_f$

Comment: well you could parametrize D but I don't think that will be a very good idea. Try assuming that $z$ is a zero and maybe try Roberts idea: If $z$ is a zero than you know that $z^5+2=-e^z \implies |z^5+2|\leq 1$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: for $z$ in the left half plane, $|e^z| \le 1$. Use Rouché.

Comment: I tried using Rouché but I dont see how you can bound the function?